# how to create a directory with date/time in foldername with Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in my batch file:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%1) DO (
    set dt="%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
    mkdir %resultsFolder%\Iteration-%%G_%dt%
)
```

But i see the output as:

```
set dt="201501231433"
mkdir C:\Temp\Iteration-1_
```

I don't see the value of "dt" in the mkdir command. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%1) DO (
    set dt=%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
    REM Updated command to use delayed 'dt' variable.
    mkdir "%resultsFolder%\Iteration-%%G_!dt!"
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Without delayed expansion, `%dt%` is evaluated when the `FOR` loop starts. In this case it is empty when the `FOR` loop is first parsed, so it will remain empty for the life of the loop. With delayed expansion, `!dt!` is evaluated on each iteration.

Note that I also tweaked the quote usage in your paths.

---

However, you really don't need to put the `dt` calculation in your `FOR` loop if your goal is for all folders to have the same timestamp. You could do the whole thing without delayed expansion by simply moving this statement:

```
set dt=%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%1) DO (
    mkdir "%resultsFolder%\Iteration-%%G_%dt%"
)
```

Comment: how do i make it create a new timestamp for every iteration?

Comment: @quldude - Not sure what you mean. According to your code, the `dt` variable would only change when the minute is updated, so it likely will not change once generated. Your `%%G` variable (which increments each pass) ensures the path is different each time.